# Does AAD B2C screens support JS widgets?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We are trying to embed a widget on the selfasserted screen. However, the widget doesnt come to life.

Can a JS widget be embedded in a B2C screen?

Answer (score 0):

While I don't fully understand what you mean by a widget, you do need to make sure that your custom policy and content definitions are configured to enable Javascript.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-and-page-layout?pivots=b2c-custom-policy